# 14.04 Wi-Fi is not working with Intel centrino 2200

Tags: kernel, internet, ubuntu-drivers, iwlwifi

I have a centrino 2200 Wi-Fi card  http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/wireless-products/centrino-wireless-n-2200-desktop.html running Ubuntu 14.04 trusty.  It connects to the network, but then I have tried pinging Google and there is nothing. My phone Wi-Fi (moto g) works just fine where my computer is. This is using the iwlwifi driver Any ideas?

Comment: Anyone?   Also tried with Ubuntu 15.04 still not working.

Comment: Tried ubuntu-mate wifi is now working fine.